# spectrum of an operator restricted to an invariant subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional real Banach space and $T\in\mathcal{L}(X)$ a continuous linear operator acting on $X$.  Suppose $W$ is a finite-codimensional $T$-invariant closed subspace of $X$, and write $S=T|_W\in\mathcal{L}(W)$ for the restriction of $T$ to $W$.

Denote by $\sigma(T)$ the spectrum of the complexification $T_\mathbb{C}\in\mathcal{L}(X_\mathbb{C})$, and similarly for $S$.  In other words, $\lambda\in\sigma(T)$ if and only if $(\lambda-T_\mathbb{C})$ is not invertible in the complex operator algebra $\mathcal{L}(X_\mathbb{C})$.

**Conjecture.**  If $\sigma(T)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ then $\sigma(S)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

**Note.**  For my purposes we can assume $X$ is reflexive and that $W=\overline{p(T)X}$ for some polynomial $p(t)\in\mathbb{R}[t]$ (with real coefficients).

I don't want to make any additional assumptions about $W$ or $S$.  However, if necessary we could make additional assumptions on $X$ and/or $T$, for instance that $X$ is a Hilbert space and that $T$ is selfadjoint.  Of course, the fewer assumptions the better.

Comment: if $T_{\mid W}-\lambda I_{\mid W} $ is invertible then it is in $\mathcal{L}(W)$, or if $T-\lambda I$ is invertible, then $T_{\mid W} -\lambda I_{\mid W}$ is invertible in $\mathcal{L}(W)$

Comment: @user1952009  What you are saying is equivalent to $\sigma(T|_W)\subseteq\sigma(T)$.  However, this is not true for all $T$-invariant subspaces $W$.  Is there something about $W$ being finite-codimensional which makes it true in this case?

Comment: finite codimensional means that $X = W \oplus U$ with $U$ finite dimensional ? and how do you get a counter-example for the general case ? (assuming the Banach space are separable and have Schauder basis, etc.)

Comment: @user1952009 Finite-codimensional means $\text{dim}(X/W)<\infty$, which is indeed equivalent to $X=W\oplus U$ with $\text{dim}(U)<\infty$.  See here for a counterexample when $W$ is not finite-codimensional:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149009/spectra-of-restrictions-of-bounded-operators

Comment: So your example is that $T$ can have an 'eigenvector' $v$ which is **not** in the Banach space, while $v_{\mid W}$ is in the Banach space. Of course  when the co-dimension is finite this cannot happen. Now, I wonder if this is the only way it can fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$W_C = \{u + iv \in X_C \mid u, v \in W\}$ is invariant under $T_C$, so we may as well forget about the real Banach spaces and consider an operator $T$ on a complex Banach space $X$ with a finite-codimensional invariant subspace $W$, such that $\sigma(T) \subseteq \mathbb R$.  The claim is that $\sigma(T|_W) \subseteq \mathbb R$.

If $\lambda \notin \sigma(T)$, $T - \lambda I$ is invertible as an operator on $X$.  Let $W$ have codimension $k$ in $X$.  Thus $X$ is spanned by $W$ and $k$ vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_k$, with $W \cap \text{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_k) = \{0\}$  Since $T-\lambda I$ is surjective, $X$ is also spanned by $(T-\lambda I)W$ and the $k$ vectors $(T-\lambda I)v_1, \ldots, (T-\lambda I)v_k$, with $(T-\lambda I) W \subseteq W$. Thus $(T-\lambda I) W$ still has codimension $k$, and so $(T-\lambda I) W = W$.  Thus $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ (as an operator on $X$) is also an inverse for $T -\lambda I$ on $W$.  This says that $\sigma(T|_W) \subseteq \sigma(T) \subseteq \mathbb R$.

EDIT: In general, without the finite-codimension assumption $\sigma(T|_W)$ might be larger than $\sigma(T)$.  However, it is always true that if $\lambda \notin \sigma(T) \cup \sigma(T|_W)$, $(T|_W - \lambda I|_W)^{-1} = (T-\lambda I)^{-1}|_W$.  Now if $\lambda$ is in the boundary of $\sigma(T|_W)$, we can take a sequence $\lambda_n \to \lambda$ with $\lambda_n \notin \sigma(T|_W)$, and we must have $\| (T|_W - \lambda_n I|_W)^{-1}\| \to \infty$.  If $\sigma(T) \subseteq \mathbb R$, we can take $\lambda_n \notin \mathbb R$, so these are also not in $\sigma(T)$, and thus 
$\|(T - \lambda_n I)^{-1}\| \ge \| (T - \lambda_n I)^{-1}|_W\|  \to \infty$, which implies $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$.  Thus the boundary of $\sigma(T|_W)$ is contained in $\mathbb R$, and this implies $\sigma(T|_W) \subset \mathbb R$.  So the finite-codimension assumption is not needed for this.

Comment: without the finite codimension, what changes in the results ?

Comment: Great, thank you again! By the way, this is the same project you helped me with before, so I will definitely have to let you know what happens when I'm completely done.

Comment: so your edit says that in general (real or complex spectrum / Banach space) the boundary of $\sigma(T_{\mid W})$ is $\subset$ $\sigma(T)$, but the uncertainty is on the interior of $\sigma(T_{\mid W})$ which isn't always $\subset \sigma(T)$.  and because the real line has an empty interior in the complex plane, the answer is always yes to Ben's question, where the assumption is that $T_{\mathbb{C}}$ has a real spectrum.